# Node.JS app with Passport crashing

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

My app works locally. I added all that I thought was necessary for Heroku

**Procfile**

```
web: node app.js
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "HipsterMatch",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.1.0",
    "jade": "*",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "nodemon": "0.7.10",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-local": "*",
    "passport-facebook": "*",
    "mongoose": "~3.6.4",
    "connect-flash": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.1",
    "npm": "1.3.14"
  }
}
```

Here are my logs

```
2013-12-27T08:40:29.457548+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=hipsterlove.herokuapp.com fwd="162.205.69.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-12-27T08:44:38.166741+00:00 heroku[api]: Add mongohq:sandbox add-on by     jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-12-27T08:44:38.186021+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-12-27T08:44:38.327041+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-12-27T08:44:40.396197+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2013-12-27T08:44:42.090303+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 37441
2013-12-27T08:44:42.092470+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-12-27T08:44:42.092672+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:72
2013-12-27T08:44:42.092911+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2013-12-27T08:44:42.092911+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2013-12-27T08:44:42.095509+00:00 app[web.1]: at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:540:74)
2013-12-27T08:44:42.095509+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2013-12-27T08:44:42.095509+00:00 app[web.1]: at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
2013-12-27T08:44:42.095509+00:00 app[web.1]: at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
2013-12-27T08:44:42.095509+00:00 app[web.1]: at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
2013-12-27T08:44:42.095509+00:00 app[web.1]: at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
2013-12-27T08:44:42.095509+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:478:10)
2013-12-27T08:44:42.095509+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
2013-12-27T08:44:42.095509+00:00 app[web.1]: at net.js:426:14
2013-12-27T08:44:43.403162+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2013-12-27T08:44:43.421294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-12-27T08:45:03.209570+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=hipsterlove.herokuapp.com fwd="162.205.69.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-12-27T08:47:32.961418+00:00 heroku[api]: Add papertrail:choklad add-on by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-12-27T08:47:33.079955+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-12-27T08:47:33.710788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-12-27T08:47:36.186033+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2013-12-27T08:47:37.958627+00:00 app[web.1]: at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:540:74)
2013-12-27T08:47:37.958627+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2013-12-27T08:47:37.958627+00:00 app[web.1]: at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
2013-12-27T08:47:37.954398+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2013-12-27T08:47:37.949510+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 32125
2013-12-27T08:47:37.952974+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-12-27T08:47:37.953554+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:72
2013-12-27T08:47:37.954045+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2013-12-27T08:47:37.958627+00:00 app[web.1]: at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
2013-12-27T08:47:37.958627+00:00 app[web.1]: at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
2013-12-27T08:47:37.958627+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:478:10)
2013-12-27T08:47:37.958627+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
2013-12-27T08:47:37.958627+00:00 app[web.1]: at net.js:426:14
2013-12-27T08:47:37.958627+00:00 app[web.1]: at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
2013-12-27T08:47:39.133359+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-12-27T08:47:39.134204+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-12-27T08:47:39.120176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2013-12-27T08:47:41.463835+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2013-12-27T08:47:42.782433+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 7709
2013-12-27T08:47:42.784187+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-12-27T08:47:42.784508+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:72
2013-12-27T08:47:42.784983+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2013-12-27T08:47:42.784983+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2013
-12-27T08:47:42.787164+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2013-12-27T08:47:42.787164+00:00 app[web.1]: at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:540:74)
2013-12-27T08:47:42.787164+00:00 app[web.1]: at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
2013-12-27T08:47:42.787164+00:00 app[web.1]: at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
2013-12-27T08:47:42.787164+00:00 app[web.1]: at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
2013-12-27T08:47:42.787164+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:478:10)
2013-12-27T08:47:42.787164+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
2013-12-27T08:47:42.787164+00:00 app[web.1]: at net.js:426:14
2013-12-27T08:47:42.787164+00:00 app[web.1]: at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
2013-12-27T08:47:44.091837+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2013-12-27T08:47:44.093316+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-12-27T08:50:30+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-12-27T08:50:55.506146+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 36c405b by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-12-27T08:50:55.532599+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-12-27T08:50:55+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-12-27T08:50:55.924898+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-12-27T08:50:57.601471+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2013-12-27T08:50:58.821299+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 44602
2013-12-27T08:50:58.823409+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:72
2013-12-27T08:50:58.823687+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2013-12-27T08:50:58.823080+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-12-27T08:50:58.823687+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2013-12-27T08:50:58.826090+00:00 app[web.1]: at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:540:74)
2013-12-27T08:50:58.826090+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
2013-12-27T08:50:58.826090+00:00 app[web.1]: at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
2013-12-27T08:50:58.826090+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2013-12-27T08:50:58.826090+00:00 app[web.1]: at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
2013-12-27T08:50:58.826090+00:00 app[web.1]: at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
2013-12-27T08:50:58.826090+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:478:10)
2013-12-27T08:50:58.826090+00:00 app[web.1]: at net.js:426:14
2013-12-27T08:50:58.826090+00:00 app[web.1]: at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
2013-12-27T08:50:59.977120+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2013-12-27T08:50:59.998919+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-12-27T08:57:32.833792+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=hipsterlove.herokuapp.com fwd="174.251.209.112" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-12-27T09:01:35.385263+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2013-12-27T09:01:36.760608+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:72
2013-12-27T09:01:36.758539+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 4749
2013-12-27T09:01:36.760891+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2013-12-27T09:01:36.760257+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-12-27T09:01:36.761120+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2013-12-27T09:01:36.763625+00:00 app[web.1]: at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
2013-12-27T09:01:36.763625+00:00 app[web.1]: at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
2013-12-27T09:01:36.763625+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2013-12-27T09:01:36.763625+00:00 app[web.1]: at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:540:74)
2013-12-27T09:01:36.763625+00:00 app[web.1]: at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
2013-12-27T09:01:36.763625+00:00 app[web.1]: at net.js:426:14
2013-12-27T09:01:36.763625+00:00 app[web.1]: at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
2013-12-27T09:01:36.763625+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:478:10)
2013-12-27T09:01:36.763625+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
2013-12-27T09:01:37.955733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2013-12-27T09:01:37.987115+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-12-27T09:01:33.253022+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

Comment: The log says it can't connect to MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in prod you are referencing your local mongoDB instance:

```
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
```

I imagine you've hardcoded these values...

The recommended way of handling connection strings like this that change from environment to environment is to use environment variables (http://12factor.net/config).

So you'll need to do the following (if you haven't already).

1) Set up a mongo instance in the cloud (MongoHQ, mongoLab, etc) (heroku makes this fairly easy).

2) If heroku hasn't set the env variables for the connection strings you'll need to do that.

**To list your env vars** (enter this on the command line):

```
heroku config -a name_of_your_heroku_app
```

**To set your env vars**:

```
heroku config:set MONGO_URL=somethingGoesHere -a name_of_your_heroku_app
```

Then in your node code you can reference that value like so:

```
var url = process.env.MONGO_URL;
```

To set your env variables locally, create a .env file in the root of your app. Running `foreman start` will run your procfile as well as loading the .env variables into memory.